How to clean meshes produced with cell fracture
I use cell fracture to break an object. The produced fragments have meshes that sometimes have 3 and sometimes 4 vertices. Is there an easy way to remesh? I tried: Object Data Properties / Remesh / Quads but the option is greyed out. When I try to add or remove vertices manually there is always a vertex missing or one too many.



I would try adding a Weld Modifier, then a Decimate modifier set to Planar with a low degree value.
